# View all Object in Django Template

Tags: python, django, templates

In this django function

```
def request(request):
    args = {"name": "name", 'message': "message"}
    return render(request, 'request.html', args)
```

the template will get {{name}} and {{message}} variable...
But apart from these two variable one can also access {{user}} and {{LANGUAGES}} object on template which are set in RequestContext by middleware.

Is there a way to displayed/render every object/variable that are sent to template either by my custom response or by any middleware like IP Address of requesting client, and other information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get all variables and obj using [debug](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#debug)

```
{% debug %}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to print this vars for debugging only, try [django debug toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`debug`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#debug) tag:

```
{% debug %}
```